# jsTree: Bind to Domain Objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jstree

I want to associate each node in my tree with a domain object. I was passing HTML data and manually storing the domain object in jQuery data:

```
$('li node description').data('obj', my_domain_object);
```

However, it seems that jsTree clears that data out during `$('#jstree_div').jstree();`.

So later, `$('li node description').data('obj')` is undefined.

What's the best practice to do this? (I'm guessing the principle would be the same for either HTML or JSON data)

Answer (score 1):

jsTree keeps the data intact, but moves it for optimization reasons [1]. So in the callback, it must be accessed via `data.node.data.some_key`. In my example, the magic incantation was:

```
$('#jsTree_div').on('select_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
        data.node.data.obj //... (instead of $('#node_id').data('obj'))
});
```

[1] "This is done because of speed. Attaching the data using jQuery's '.data()' every time a node is redrawn proved to be rather slow." - Ivan Bozhanov, jsTree creator https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jstree/w97E8uG_Bd0/enYklH-B1-cJ